# Table creation in ms access using matlab

Tags: matlab

How to create table in ms access using Matlab?

The table name is given by the user at run time

```
exec(conn,'Create table Employee(Name varchar,Address varchar)');
```

This create the table with name `Employee` but this name should be given at run time by user.

Answer (score 0):

You may use concatenated strings

```
tablename = 'Users';
exec(conn,['Create table ' tablename '(Name varchar,Address varchar)']);
```